# Example of two divergent series whose sum is indeterminate

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Can you suggest an example of two series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$ and $\sum_{n \geq 0}b_n$, **both divergent** (i.e. the sequences of partial sums do have limits but the limit is $\pm \infty$) such that

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n+b_n$$

is **indeterminate**? (That is the sequence of partial sums does not have limit)

Comment: With "indeterminate" you mean oscillating, right ?

Comment: @Peter Yes (such that the limit of partial sum sequence does not exist)

Comment: I think $a_n=\sin(n\pi/2)+1$ and $b_n=-1$ satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider sequences:
$a_n:=2$ for even $n$ and $a_n:=1$ for odd $n$,
$b_n:=-1$ for even $n$ and $b_n:=-2$ for odd $n$.
Then:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = +\infty$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = -\infty$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1},$$ which is indeterminate.